# Python script not executing pickle.load when called from nodejs app

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have an nodejs app which calls python script from a controller. Scripts run fine when I run from terminal directly and works fine as well when called from node app but it only stucks on this specific line `model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))`. Any help would be appreciated.

predict.py

```
import sys
import json
import pickle
import os

def get_size(weight, height, age):
  model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
  return model.predict([[height,weight,age,bmi]])[0]
    
calculated_size = get_size(69,167,26)
print(calculated_size)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

results.js

```
const scriptPath = path.dirname(require.main.filename) + '/python-scripts/predict.py';
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', [ scriptPath, 'user_inputs', JSON.stringify(results) ], {cwd: path.dirname(require.main.filename)+'/python-scripts'});
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', async (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing python version in spawn:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', [ scriptPath, 'user_inputs', JSON.stringify(results) ], {cwd: path.dirname(require.main.filename)+'/python-scripts'});
```